# Compile error creating message_filter with std_msgs/String

Tags: ros-lunar, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Based on https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer I am trying to subscribe a node on two topics. I made two of the talker nodes like in https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29. One talker publishes on chatter and other on chatter1. So below is the code for listenerMultiple.cpp :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

using namespace message_filters;
using namespace std_msgs;
using namespace std;


void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
        ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        ros::init(argc, argv, "listenerMultipleTopics");
        ros::NodeHandle n;

        message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> camera_sub(n, "chatter",1);
        message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> imu_sub(n, "chatter2",1);

        typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<String, String> MySyncPolicy;
        Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), camera_sub, imu_sub); // adding these lines create problem!!!
        sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&chatterCallback, _1, _2)); // adding these lines create problem!!!

        ros::spin();
        return 0;
}
```

**edit**
gvdhorn explained this won't work because there is no header for the String messages. So how can I take the String from the two topics and concatenate them?

This creates a super huge compilation error (how could I solve this?) :

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/e9b7cb1f53c1e51e53e2361ea474e535

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282167/compile-error-creating-message_filter-with-std_msgs/string/) by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just about all of the `message_filter` filters only work with messages with a [Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) field, as the filters need timestamps to work with.

`std_msgs/String` doesn't have a header, so that's most likely why you get the compilation error.

Search for `header` on the [wiki/message_filters - Time Synchronizer](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer) page you linked.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-08**:
Hello gvdhoorn,
So how can I use the messages received from the two talkers and stack them into a vector?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
If you have no requirements for a particular order, I suggest you write a callback that does something like:

```
void callback(... msg)
{
    my_vector_.push_back(msg->data);
}
```

provided `my_vector_` is a `std::vector<std::string>` and is in scope, that should work.

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-09**:
But my_vector_ would be defined in the main function, so how can it be in the scope of the callback?
Sould I pass the my_vector_ by reference to the callback? But  then should I bind the callback or something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
Either place variables in the global scope, or use a class.

But this is more a C++ question, not a ROS issue.

**Comment by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on 2018-02-09**:
okay, I am going for the class way. Thanks!